# Using business check to pay at retail

Tags: united-states, check, checking-account, business

I recently opened a LLC bank account, and need to buy some equipment (computer parts) for the day-to-day operation. I want to buy in a physical retail store for convenience.

Can I use a business check for this?

If so, do I just write the necessary information and sign on the spot at the cashier? Do all major store chains offer this option?

If not, what are my options (besides credit cards)?

Sorry for so basic question, and thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd imagine it varies from store to store and will probably be treated as a personal check. But that's really just a wild guess based on logic and some meager understanding of human behavior.

Comment: Depending on the store you go to, some might not take checks at all.

Comment: If they are the fully printed ones not the temp ones, they should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can just buy the items personally and then submit an expense report to the company to get reimbursed. Keep all the receipts. Paying with a company check is also fine, but you might run into problems with stores not accepting checks.

Comment: Wherever possible, the cleanest thing to do with your business records is just keep them completely separate from your personal life. It definitely can be acceptable to do as you're describing, but if the OP already has a business bank account, then starting to pay things personally and repay through the business is losing some of the benefits of having that account in the first place.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon, Right, but faced with a store that doesn't take company checks, I would think plan (b) is to buy it with your personal funds and submit an expense claim, rather than spend the time to try another store.